# How to add index to an existing table?

Tags: cratedb

I create a table and filled it with approx 1Mio data.
But now, the select query takes up to 16 seconds (select by date).

How can I add an index to an existing table to improve the search performance?
I dont quite get it from here:
https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/reference/alter_table.html#partition-clause

Something like this would be nice:

`alter table table_name reset column_name index using PLAIN`

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

'PLAIN' is the default index and doesn't need to be turned on explicitly: https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/ddl/indices_full_search.html#plain-index-default - if you need different indexing you need to reindex your data. either by 'SELECT INTO' or by dumping the data with 'COPY TO' and load back with 'COPY TO'